# #1054 - Unknown column 'ord' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using mySQL.

I got error when I tried to add parameter to SQL query which supposed to sort my results:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'ord' in 'field list'

```
SELECT tkt.* , ord = 0 
            FROM tkts_follows AS t2f 
            JOIN tkts_topics AS tkt ON (t2f.tktID = tkt.id 
                                    AND t2f.type = 'pin' 
                                    AND t2f.userID = 1 )
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT * , ord = 1 
            FROM tkts_topics AS tkt
            WHERE  (1=1 ) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM tkts_follows AS t2f 
                            WHERE t2f.tktID = tkt.id AND t2f.type = 'pin' AND t2f.userID = 1) 
                            ORDER BY ord, last_update DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: what is `ord = 0` in the select ?

Comment: new parameter that i'm using in order to sort my results - @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: "parameter" in what sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are setting some ordering number and it needs to be as

```
SELECT tkt.* , 0 as ord
FROM tkts_follows AS t2f 
JOIN tkts_topics AS tkt ON t2f.tktID = tkt.id 
AND t2f.type = 'pin'
AND t2f.userID = 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * , 1 as ord 
FROM tkts_topics AS tkt
WHERE  1=1  AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM tkts_follows AS t2f 
WHERE t2f.tktID = tkt.id AND t2f.type = 'pin' AND t2f.userID = 1
) 
ORDER BY ord, last_update DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be '0 AS ord' or '1 AS ord'.  Also, when sorting on a UNION ALL, I would recommend putting everything in a sub-query and ordering the results, as ordering on a UNION will give you unexpected results.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        tkt.*
        , 0 AS ord
    FROM tkts_follows AS t2f 
        JOIN tkts_topics AS tkt ON t2f.tktID = tkt.id
            AND t2f.type = 'pin'
            AND t2f.userID = 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT
        *
        , 1 AS ord
    FROM tkts_topics AS tkt
    WHERE  (1=1)
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT * 
            FROM tkts_follows AS t2f 
            WHERE t2f.tktID = tkt.id
                AND t2f.type = 'pin'
                AND t2f.userID = 1
        ) 
) AS UNIONS
ORDER BY ord, last_update DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```